# Cant use change play plugins in test running(fakeApp)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

Im trying to test with different mocked plugins in place of the real one. It works fine with one mock, but when I have two it always uses the first one.

```
class UserSpec extends Specification {
  "User" should {
    val fakeAppA = new FakeApplication(
      additionalPlugins = Seq(
        "FakeServiceA"
        )
      )

    "have FakeServiceA " in running(fakeAppA) {
      UserController.doit() === "FakeServiceA"
    }

    val fakeAppB = new FakeApplication(
      additionalPlugins = Seq(
        "FakeServiceB"
        )
      )

    "have FakeServiceB" in running(fakeAppB) {
      // doesnt work gets FakeServiceA
      UserController.doit() === "FakeServiceB"
    }
  }
}

object UserController extends Controller {
  val service = Play.application.plugin[Service]
    .getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("Service not loaded"))

  def doit() = service.serviceIt()
}

class Service(app: Application) extends Plugin {
  def serviceIt(): String = "Service"
}

class FakeServiceA(app: Application) extends Service(app) {
  override def serviceIt(): String = "FakeServiceA"
}

class FakeServiceB(app: Application) extends Service(app) {
  override def serviceIt(): String = "FakeServiceB"
}
```

Comment: You can probably post the code of `UserController` to make it more clear. You can also accept you own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The controller isnt recreated for each test because its a scala object. Thus you should reference the plugin by a def, rather than a val.

```
 object UserController extends Controller {
-       val service = Play.application.plugin[Service]
+       def service = Play.application.plugin[Service]
        .getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("Service not loaded"))
```